# Can anyone fix my ListView problem in xamarin.android?

Tags: android, listview, compiler-errors, xamarin.android

Can you guys help me with my code?

```
list_bt = FindViewById(Resource.Id.list_view);
```

it says "'Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for "list_view""
but I already stated in my .xml file for the ListView id to be list_view. Below is my .cs file

```
Android.App;
using Android.Bluetooth;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Widget;

namespace Test1
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        CheckBox enableBt, enableVisible;
        TextView nameBt;
        Button search_button;
        ListView list_bt;

        private BluetoothAdapter BA;
        private JavaSet<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            enableBt = (CheckBox)FindViewById(Resource.Id.enableBt);
            enableVisible = (CheckBox)FindViewById(Resource.Id.enableVisible);
            nameBt = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.text1);
            search_button = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.search_button);
            list_bt = FindViewById(Resource.Id.list_view);
        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine on my side, don't forget to save the xml file before building the project . If it still doesn't work , you would better share a sample which contains the error so that I can test it on my side .

Answer (score 0):

I have had same problem recently. Probably Visual studio environment is acting up so you can delete all code in `Resource.designer.cs` and compile again. Also, you can clear your .xml file compile and then return all code and compile again. By the way, `nameBt = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.text1);` looks better as `nameBt = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.text1);`